# Union of cte and declare

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can i pass union of both these statements

```
with temp as (
  select distinct max(rundate)as Rundate,max(LoadDate) as Loaddate
  from ods.cfageing_monthend 
  group by month(rundate) & year(rundate)
)
(select * 
 from ods.CFAgeing_MonthEnd 
 where loaddate in (select loaddate from temp) 
   and rundate in (select rundate from temp)
)

declare @maxdate as datetime
set @maxdate=(select max(rundate) from FactCFAgeing)
select * from FactCFAgeing where loaddate=(DATEADD(day,-1,@maxdate))
```

Comment: The logic here isn't obvious to me. What are you trying to do? Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can only use cte once, so you cannot union this on your next select.

if you have same columns of `FactCFAgeing` and `ods.CFAgeing_MonthEnd`.

You can use this query.

```
with temp as (
    select distinct max(rundate)as Rundate,max(LoadDate) as Loaddate 
    from ods.cfageing_monthend 
    group by year(rundate), month(rundate)

) select t1.* from ods.CFAgeing_MonthEnd t1
    inner join temp t2 on t2.loaddate = t1.loaddate and t2.rundate = t1.rundate
  union all
  select * from FactCFAgeing 
    where loaddate=(select max(rundate) from FactCFAgeing)
```